# Flash ESP8266 from SPIFFS filesystem

Tags: esp8266

I'm searching for a way to flash an ESP8266 *programmatically*, i.e, without user interaction (and especially without the Arduino IDE).

Assuming I can put the program to be flashed on the SPIFFS filesystem, is there a way to flash the ESP with that file?

Comment: yes, but why store it in SPIFFS? see the ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer and ESP8266httpUpdate libraries examples

Comment: I said I wanted no user interaction.  Besides, I don't want a server in my ESP.

Comment: how do you get the file to SPIFFS? the ESP8266httpUpdate library downloads an update bin from a server and updates using the Updater object without storing the bin to SPIFFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is (or at least WAS possible a few years ago) to have an ESP8266 self-program if you can get the file onto the file system, by using the `Update` core that is used by OTA and httpUpdate. This was a example program to do it, but I don't know if it still works. I would also suggest that you look at using LittleFS instead of SPIFFS as the latter has been depreciated.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <FS.h>
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  SPIFFS.begin();
  Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");

  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);

  File file = SPIFFS.open("/firmware-update.bin", "r");
    
  uint32_t maxSketchSpace = (ESP.getFreeSketchSpace() - 0x1000) & 0xFFFFF000;
  if (!Update.begin(maxSketchSpace, U_FLASH)) { //start with max available size
    Update.printError(Serial);
    Serial.println("ERROR");
  }
 
  while (file.available()) {
    uint8_t ibuffer[128];
    file.read((uint8_t *)ibuffer, 128);
    Serial.println((char *)ibuffer);
    Update.write(ibuffer, sizeof(ibuffer));
  }
 
  Serial.print(Update.end(true));
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
  file.close();
}

void loop() {     
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Also thanks for the suggestion of LittleFS, I will consider it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it still works, but now you need to pass data as a pointer:

```
Update.write(&ibuffer, sizeof(ibuffer));
```

Comment: it is an array so it is a pointer already